# why is this error showing

Tags: codeigniter

I am using CI for my web-site. While programming CMS for the same I faced no problem but when I am programming the same for user-end I am getting error as:
"404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found."
What am i doing wrong?? Any help/suggestions is warmly welcome.Thank you.

In Controller(model.phpl):

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Model extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('user_model');
            $this->load->model('common'); 
            $this->load->model('home_model');
            $this->load->model('page_model');
    }

        function _remap($method , $params = array())
        {
            $this->menu = $this->common->createMenuArr();
            $this->index();
        }
        function index()
        {
            $data['sliderArr'] = $this->user_model->sliders();
            $this->load->view('index', $data);
        }

}
```

In Model(user_model.php):

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class User_model extends CI_Model{
    function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            //$this->load->database(); 
    }
       function sliders()
        {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT slider FROM tbl_sliders ORDER BY slider_id DESC")->result_array();
            return $query;
        }

}
```

and finally in view(index.php):

```
<div id="slideContainer">
            <div id="slideShim">
                            <?php
                                if(!empty($sliderArr))
                                {
                                    foreach($sliderArr as $slider)
                                    { ?>
                                        <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/sliders/<?php echo $slider['slider'];?>"</a>
                                   <?php }
                                }
                            ?>


        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: no @user1537158 the same problem persists..

Comment: What is the url you are accessing and getting the error?

Comment: @sammy i really wouldnt recommend using MODEL as ur CONTROLLER name

Comment: @AlphaMale i am using base_url()

Comment: and whats your base url?

Comment: @sammy u get the 404 while clicking on the image or while accessing the controller method slider () ?

Comment: @AlphaMale $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/trust/';

Comment: and what is your default controller?

Comment: @user1537158 changing MODEL as controller name didn't help either

Comment: @sammy u get the 404 while clicking on the image or while accessing the controller method slider () ?

Comment: @AlphaMale didn't get you. bdw in my application/controllers folder i have admin.php for CMS, ajax.php and user.php for user end

Comment: @sammy alphaMale wants you to check application->config->routes and check for default controller , the controller that must be excuted when u first load your website

Comment: @user1537158 i got the error while i am trying to view the index page which is default page while opening the website

Comment: yes , that is what @AlphaMale suggested , goto application->config->routes and there set $route['default_controller'] = "index"; assuming that index.php is the controller u want to execute when your website first loads

Comment: @AlphaMale..thank you guyz ... that one helped. application->config->routes
thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Application -> Config -> Routes**.

And Set `$route['default_controller'] = "index";  //whatever your controller name is on which you want your application to route by default`

Hope this helps.